# Issue with : standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, devops, dockerhub

I wanted to test the scratch Docker image to run a simple binary, but seems that it does not work

```
FROM gcc:4.9 AS build
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN gcc -o hello main.c
CMD ["./hello"]

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build /usr/src/myapp/hello .
CMD ["/hello"]
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

```
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Found out !
my hello binary has dynamic linking to libc library.
while scratch image seems not having it.

so by statically linking, it works : RUN gcc -o hello **-static** main.c